# Display a chunk of code after the last post within a while loop in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I'm currently running a `while` loop that is pulling items from Pods depending on which category they are assigned too. So if I click through "Healthcare" it will grab all the items from the main pod within that category and show them on the following page (`category.php`)

I need to be able to insert a section of code that will only show after the very last post. I'm using pagination as well so I need to make it visible on the last page of pagination only. I have tried a few methods but nothing has worked yet.

The code for the loop is as follows:

```
<?php // Displays the Panels to each Project.

//get the current slug 
$slug = pods_v( 'last', 'url' );
//get pods object
$mypod = pods( 'portfolio', $slug );

$params = array(
'orderby' => 'menu_order ASC',
'where' => 'category.slug = "' . $slug . '"',
'limit' => 5,
);
$portfolioPods = pods('portfolio', $params, array());?>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6s teambox limiter">    
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 infobox_portfolio">
    <h1 class="header shrink">Various Projects</h1>
    <p><a class="btns btn btn_foot" href="/<?php echo '' .$slug . '-projects';?>">View these projects</a><!--.--></p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 proj-img-cont l-img-border sneaky">
    <a href=""><?php echo '<img src="' . z_taxonomy_image_url($category->term_id) . '" />';?></a>
</div>
</div>

<?php
while ($portfolioPods->fetch()) {
?>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6s teambox limiter">    
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 infobox_portfolio">
    <h1 class="header shrink"><?php echo $portfolioPods->field('title'); ?></h1>
    <!--<p><?php// the_time('F jS - Y'); ?></p>
    <p><?php// echo $portfolioPods->field('summary'); ?></p>-->
    <p><a class="btns btn btn_foot" href="<?php echo $portfolioPods->display(the_permalink); ?>">View this project</a><!--.--></p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 proj-img-cont l-img-border">
    <a href="<?php echo $portfolioPods->display(the_permalink); ?>"><img class="team current-dev respond" src="<?php echo $portfolioPods->display('landing_page_thumbnail'); ?>" /></a>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?> 
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $portfolioPods->pagination( array( 'type' => 'advanced' ) );    ?><!--<?php //echo '' .$slug . '-projects';?>-->
</div>
</div>
```

I think I need to add an `if` statement so that once it reaches the last post, it will then show this code/text. I'm just unsure how to do so with all the elements I'm pulling in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop, you can check if there is a next or previous post using `get_next_post(true)` and `get_previous_post(true)`, respectively. Depending on what you define as the 'last' post, assigning the return value of either of those functions would serve as a good conditional to use in your if block.

```
$previous_post = get_previous_post(true);
if ($previous_post) {
//do something
}
```

Hope that works for you.